# Spring Boot : Sharing a bean between different components

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a bean which I've declared in my bean config as thus:

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {
    @Bean
    public MemberDTO getMemberDTO() {
        return new MemberDTO();
    }
}
```

When a user calls my service, I use the username and password they've provided to call the endpoint of a different service to get the user's information:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationProvider.class);

    private @Autowired MemberDTO memberDTO;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String loginGeniuneFailMessage = "";
        boolean loginGeniuneFail = false;
        try {
            String username = authentication.getName();
            String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

            String endPoint = credentialsBaseUrl + "/api/login";

            HttpResponse<MemberDTO> response_auth = Unirest.get(endPoint)
                    .basicAuth(username, password)
                    .header("Accept", "*/*")
                    .asObject(MemberDTO.class);

            int status_auth = response_auth.getStatus();

            if (status_auth == 200) {
                if (response_auth.getBody() == null) {
                    LOGGER.info("account validation - could not parse response body to object");

                    UnirestParsingException ex = response_auth.getParsingError().get();
                    LOGGER.error("parsing error: ", ex);
                } else {
                    memberDTO = response_auth.getBody();
                }
            }

            ...
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

I want to store the user's information in the memberDTO and use the memberDTO elsewhere in a different component, rather than calling the login API every time:

```
@Component
public class MemberLogic {
    private @Autowired MemberDTO memberDTO;

    public ResponseEntity<?> processMemberInformation(WrapperDTO wrapperDTO, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasFieldErrors()) {
            String errors = result.getFieldErrors().stream()
                    .map(p -> p.getDefaultMessage()).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("An error occured while trying to persist information: " + errors);
        }

        String name = memberDTO.getName();

        ...
    }
}
```

The problem now is the "memberDTO.getName()" is returning null, even though this value is being set from the initial API call in CustomAuthenticationProvider.

My questions are: why isn't this working? And is this the best approach to take for something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you're not using `SecurityContext`?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Is that relevant to the direct question?

Comment: Basically you are trying to store the information about logged in user and use it wherever it is required in the application. As @chrylis-onstrike- suggested, it's good to use the SecurityContext to store the logged in user details. This is the standard way to fetch logged in user details in Spring based applications.

Comment: @NageswaraRaOMaridu While this is the recommended way to work with user information, how does it answer the direct question : *why isn't this working?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My questions are: why isn't this working? And is this the best approach to take for something like this?

This doesn't work because *Java* uses *pass-by-value* semantics instead of *pass-by-reference* semantics. What this means is that the statement `memberDTO = response_auth.getBody();` does not really make the *Spring* container start pointing to the `MemberDTO` returned by `response_auth.getBody()`. It only makes the `memberDTO` reference in `CustomAuthenticationProvider` point to the object in the response. The *Spring* container still continues to refer to the original `MemberDTO` object.

One way to fix this would be to define a `DAO` class that can be used for interacting with `DTO` instances rather than directly creating a `DTO` bean :

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {
    @Bean
    public MemberDAO getMemberDAO() {
        return new MemberDAO();
    }
}
```

`CustomAuthenticationProvider` can then set the `MemberDTO` in the `MemberDAO` by using : `memberDAO.setMemberDTO(response_auth.getBody());`

Finally, `MemberLogic` can access the `MemberDTO` as `String name = memberDAO.getMemberDTO().getName();`

**Note :** Instead of returning the `MemberDTO` from the `MemberDAO`, the `MemberDAO` can define a method called `getName` which extracts the name from the `MemberDTO` and returns it. (*Tell Don't Ask* principle). That said and as suggested in the comments, the best practice would be to use a `SecurityContext` to store the user information.

Comment: Thanks so much! I did some research and I was able to use the SecurityContext as advised, to pass extra details of the user, and retrieve those details in my other components

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you can not override a spring bean "content" like this `memberDTO = response_auth.getBody();`  because it changes only the instance variable for the given bean. (And its also not good because its out of the spring boot context and it overrides only the field dependency for this singleton bean)

You should not use a normal spring bean for holding data (a state). All the spring beans are singleton by default and you could have some concurrency problems.

For this you should use a database, where you write your data or something like a session bean.